# How to filter out letters and pair the same numbers?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet with columns. The columns have numbers with varying letters like `b 123` and `b123`.

How can I delete the b's just to have the numbers? I want to focus only to the numbers so that I can pair the same numbers with each other.

Answer (score 2):

You can use "text functions".
To extract part of string:

> MID(text, start_num, num_chars)
>   example: say that in cell A1 you have text "b 123", put in B1
>   MID(A1, 2, 100)
>   you must see " 123" in B1 as result

Warning: the value of third parameter (100) can be specified in you case or with a constant big enough (some risk!) or using the function LEN(text), so LEN(A1).

In the result remain the space, you can dispose trailing and ending spaces with function

> TRIM(text)

The complete function can be:

> TRIM(MID(A1, 2, LEN(A1)))

Here a link to Excel Text functions reference: http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/text-functions-reference-HP010079191.aspx